# Two groups acting iteratively on one space

Tags: finite-groups

I have two groups $(Z_2)^n$ equiped with a pointwise binary addition operator and $S_n$ acting iteratively on the space $X=\{0,1\}^n$, in the following way: Fix $x\in X$. At each iteration we apply a transposition from $S_n$ to $x$ and then an element of $Z_2^n$ acts on the result, and so on. For example, fix $(1,0,0)\in X$, then for $(13)\in S_3$ and $(1,1,0)\in Z_2^3$, we have

$$(1,1,0) \circ ((13) \circ (1,0,0)) = (1, 1,0) \circ (0, 0,1) = (1,1,1)$$

Now choose other elements from $S_3$ and $Z_2^3$ And apply them to $(1,1,1)$. Continue this process.

How can one study this iterative process? Is there a way of mixing these two groups and define a group action?

Comment: So, like a Markov chain?

Comment: Like an iteratative function system. Think about the action of each group as a function.

Comment: So is the choice of  transposition and translation vector fixed ahead of time?

Comment: No. Assume that is done randomly, so it could be thought as a stochastic process that is obtained by sequential actions of two different groups to a fix point x.